# null==instance instead of instance==null

Tags: java

I have seen at many 3rd party code fragments where in some condition `null==instance` in used instead of `instance==null` like `if(null== connection)`.

Just curious, does this approach makes any impact on conditional statements or people are just cool to use it?

Comment: [Yoda conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) Using `if(constant == variable)` instead of `if(variable == constant)`, like `if(4 == foo)`. Because it's like saying "if blue is the sky" or "if tall is the man". http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/

Comment: I'd expect the compiled bytecode to be exactly the same in both cases -- one `ifnull` instruction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most common reasons I hear quoted for using this are:

1. It's clever and cool.
2. It helps protect against assignment vs. comparison errors, since you can't assign to `null`.

I vehemently argue against the former, since "clever" very easily becomes "difficult to maintain" in any codebase.  The latter has validity, though I think decent test coverage can accomplish the same task with more added value.

Personally I don't care for this style because it doesn't read correctly for me.  Generally I like code to "read like prose" to make it easy to follow.  And consider two prose statements:

1. The object is empty.
2. Empty is the object.

The former sounds more natural to me.

Comment: +1 for the second reason.

Comment: @David Thanks for the answer and adding `vehemently` to my dictionary! god bless you!

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no any difference.

This is just a *code style*, that may appeal in some cases useful to some, when `null` is immediately manifested like a first value in conditional statement so makes it more explicit.

Also imagine in case when "instance" may appear not just an instance of type, but some expression, say  `(()=> { .... })`. You need in that case, first read an expression to the end, after see what is a condition, instead you see condition in first place.

Answer (score 5):

I think it comes from C/C++ where you could accidentally assign a value without the compiler noticing:

```
if(variable = 0) { ... }
```

This causes no error and the condition is always false and the variable is assigned 0.
So people started to strictly use the other form:

```
if(0 = variable) { ... }
```

which causes an error since 0 can not be assigned a value.

The notation `if(null == variable)` may be readable enough, but what about `if(b == a)` where **b is a constant** and **a a variable**? In this case, readability is a problem.

Comment: But you would get this warning: `suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value`... and you are using warnings, right?

Comment: @AKHolland IMHO using Yoda notation to avoid accidental assignment is obsolete with a modern compiler. As I said, this probably comes from a time where the compiler did **not** warn you.

Answer (score 4):

No difference, except if you mistype and do `=` instead of `==` the compiler will complain as you can't assign to null.